# Can I use JSF 2.0 annotations in a JSF 1.2 application?

Tags: java, jsf-2, annotations, jsf-1.2

What part of the JSF 2.0 framework handles the annotations? I really would like to add them to a JSF 1.2 application. Is that even a realistic goal?

Comment: Probably not. Why not migrate the new application to use JSF 2.0? The semantics of existing JSF 1.2 constructs shouldn't have changed much in 2.0.

Comment: I am using Xpages from IBM which is stuff ontop of the JSF 1.2, so sadly not an option for me.

Comment: You might consider Seam or Spring annotations as alternatives. There are versions of these that should work with JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JSF 2.0 annotations in JSF 1.2 without basically upgrading the whole thing to JSF 2.0. You can however use [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html) annotations ([`@Named`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html), [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) and likes) in JSF 1.2. As you're using old JSF 1.2, I'll assume that you're using an old Java EE 5 / Servlet 2.5 container. Although CDI is part of Java EE 6, you can use a standalone CDI implementation in a Java EE 5 / Servlet 2.5 compatible container. One of the CDI implementations is [JBoss Weld](http://seamframework.org/Weld). It's even [officially](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/gettingstarted.html#tomcat) supported on Tomcat 6.

CDI will cover the most what JSF 2.0 offers as managed bean annotations, including the three main scopes [`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html), [`@SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) and [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html). CDI does only not offer a fullworthy equivalent of the JSF 2.0 [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) annotation. Closest what it offers is the [`@ConversationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html), but you'd need to manually start and end the injected [`Conversation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/Conversation.html).

CDI does not offer annotations which can replace `@FacesConverter`, `@FacesValidator` and likes, but that is likely not your major requirement.